# Comparing 2 columns of a excel including duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Have 2 columns A and B both contain file names. There are duplicates so there might be more records in column A as compared to column B. I want to create a third column which states there is no match for the same file name in column B Please find the attached excel. Right now I am doing this manually. Is it possible to do this using a ifcountif or a vlookup?

[image: Screenshot of excel]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A1,B$1:B$3,0),"No Match")
```

If there is a match, then the match returns the position number of the match.
Just drag down, edit the array for B as needed.

Comment: @pnuts as you say, unclear, but the solution I offered does assume that col B only has unique names as the OP did state duplicates may be in column A...